# ScrollView is getting focused by talkback instead of its child TextViews

Tags: android, android-scrollview, accessibility

I have a ScrollView with multiple TextViews inside (which are not focusable by default). When I use TalkBack to navigate through the screen, TalkBack only focuses the whole ScrollView and reads all of its content at once.

I tried a couple things to make TalkBack focus each TextView instead of the ScrollView container, but I couldn't find a good way to do it. Here's a sample code:

```
<ScrollView
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:fillViewport="true">

   <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="vertical">

      <TextView
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="@string/string"/>

      <TextView
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="@string/a_string"/>

      <TextView
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="@string/some_string"/>

   </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

I tried to add `android:focusable=true` to each TextView, which made them focusable with TalkBack, but the parent ScrollView was still getting focused first. Ideally, I would prefer if the ScrollView was completely ignored by TalkBack, and the focus goes straight to its child Views.

How can I make TalkBack completely ignore the ScrollView and focuses each child TextView one by one instead?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?  I'm facing a very similar issue now.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `android:importantForAccessibility="no"` on ScrollView to let talkback bypass the rootview and iterate through child views directly